# Angular internationalization (i18n) and *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, ngfor

I have a simple generic component in `Angular` which receives a list of strings and creates a radio group for these strings:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'radio-group',
  templateUrl: 
           `<div *ngFor="let item of items">
                 <label for="input_{{item}}">{{item}}</label>
                 <input type="radio" id="input_{{item}}" value="{{item}}" [formControl]="radioControl">
           </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./radio-group.component.scss']
})
export class RadioGroupComponent {
    @Input()
    items: string[];
    @Input()
    radioControl: FormControl;
}
```

I need the radio group labels internationalized.
The official `i18n` [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html) of `Angular` talks only about static HTML.

Is there any way to internationalize dynamic components (like `*ngFor` entries) with `i18n` template translation?

I'm aware of `ngx-translate` way, I'm interested particularly in `i18n` way.

Comment: Better would be to do this in .ts but that is not yet available as a part of angular2 i18n. Similar request https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12008 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the very same thing and also for an option to do dynamic translation without ngx-translate.
[ocombe](https://github.com/ocombe) seems to be the one responible for i18n at Angular. In this GitHub issue [#16477](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477) he posted some kind of roadmap for i18n in Angular.

> ▢ Use translation strings outside of a template - [#11405](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405) [blocked by runtime i18n]

As you can see this feature is not implemented in Angular yet but it's planned. The issue that is blocking this feature luckily is in progress:

> ▢ Runtime i18n (one bundle for all locales with AOT) - [working on it]

I don't remember where I read it but I think ocombe wrote, they want to implement this feature still in Angular 5 so it might be available before spring 2018 (the [Angular roadmap](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_SCHEDULE.md#tentative-schedule-after-september-2017) says Angular 6 will be published in spring 2018)

> Date: March/April 2018;    Stable Release: 6.0.0

ocombe just posted [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405#issuecomment-353711095) today:

> I'm not the one working on this feature, and it's the holidays break, I'll let you know as soon as I know more

So all that remains is to use ngx-translate if you cannot wait, or you could subscribe to these GitHub issues [#11405](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405) & [#16477](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477) and get updated until they make this feature available. Hopefully early 2018 :)

PS: as far as I understood they also want to implement dynamic translation, but I think it wont be available before Angular 6.

**UPDATE:**

Now it's official: Runtime i18n wont be before Angular 6 (see: [11405#issuecomment-358449205](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405#issuecomment-358449205))

**EDIT:**
I found a dirty hack to do that. you can create hidden div tags for your translations and save them via ViewChildren in a map for further use. You could even subscribe to the elements to update them.

```js
@ViewChildren('test') myChildren; // the class needs to implement AfterViewInit
myMap = new Map();
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myChildren.forEach(value => this.myMap.set(value.nativeElement.getAttribute('name'), value.nativeElement.innerHTML));
  console.log(this.myMap);
}
```

Comment: You can follow the progress of the new Ivy renderer, which will make runtime i18n available here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21706

Comment: looks like i18n with more features is a step closer now :)
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405#issuecomment-375769568

Answer (score 3):

In Angular 9 you can use global `$localize` function like this:

```js
$localize`String to translate`
```

Great article on this: https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/12/10/angular-localize/

Answer (score 0):

I am using @ngx-translate. What I did is, I declare the content that I want to translate in both language files, in my case `es.json`, and `en.json`.

**es.json:**

```
        "CONTENTS": {
    "CONT_1": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_2": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_3": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_4": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_5": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_6": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_7": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_8": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_9": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_10": "TEXTO_1",
    "CONT_11": "TEXTO_1"
}
```

**en.json**:

```
    "CONTENTS": {
    "CONT_1": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_2": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_3": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_4": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_5": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_6": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_7": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_8": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_9": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_10": "TEXT_1",
    "CONT_11": "TEXT_1"
}
```

In the component that I want to translate, in my case the `contents.component.ts`, I: i) declare an array of contents; ii) inject the translate Service; iii) set it; iv) loop a for in which you construct an object that looks like this,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contents',
  templateUrl: './contents.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contents.component.css']
})
export class ContentsComponent implements OnInit {
  // i) Declare an array
  public contents = [];
  // inject the translateService
  constructor(public translateService: TranslateService) {
    // iii) set it
    translateService.addLangs(['es', 'en']);
    translateService.setDefaultLang('es');
    const browserLang = translateService.getBrowserLang();
    translateService.use(browserLang.match(/es|en/) ? browserLang : 'es');
    // loop for build a content object and push to the array
    for (let index = 1; index <= 11; index++) {
      const contentObj = {
        id: index,
        content: 'CONTENTS.CONT_' + index.toString()
      };
      this.contents.push(contentObj);
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Finally, in my contents.component.html looks like this

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor= "let content of contents" >
        {{  content.content | translate }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can improve this code and make it better :)  I Hope could be useful.