# Angular i18n - Interpolation for collections clarification?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, internationalization

I've been looking into how to use i18n for translations in an Angular app. My struggle is with string interpolation, it seems this has not been implemented into Angular yet.

Goal: Use i18n to translate string interpolation of collection in an Angular app to have a Spanish version.

What I've done: I've been doing a lot of research, and the workarounds I've seen mentioned are:

1. **Polyfill**: ( https://github.com/ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill ) (and referenced here: [angular-i18n Angular 6 Internationalisation : How to deal with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839676/angular-i18n-angular-6-internationalisation-how-to-deal-with-variables) )
2. **Hidden div**: ([Angular internationalization (i18n) and *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824611/angular-internationalization-i18n-and-ngfor) )
3. **Verbose method**: using n-container and ngswitch. Seems the least clean way: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405#issuecomment-415731284

For a collection like an array, or a database table, how are these workarounds creating separate i18n tags for each element? Will it end up showing just one tag for all elements of the collection?

For example: If you have an array for "Gender", with values of "Male" and "Female", what will happen?

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender.value">
             {{ gender.viewVal }}
</mat-option>
```

In the polyfill they mention:

```
test {{myVar}} !", {myVar: "^_^"})
```

Does that mean "^_^" is the translation? It's done directly in the typescript, not in an xlf file?
If you use a hidden div, how does using the typescript file affect the xlf? The verbose method seems easiest to understand but not good for scalable, what if you have a dropdown with 10+ items, then that really bulks up the code.

What is the best way to go about this goal? I'm not sure I properly understand how the polyfill works and there is not much documentation on these ways of translation.

Comment: Are you bound to the demand using i18n-translation with angular build-in tools? Or are you free to decide which 3rd-party tool to apply?

Comment: We have put some structure around the i18n and have translated a all of the site that is not variables, but I am open to hearing different options, what were you thinking?